# How to change a phtml file in the vendor/ folder?

Tags: magento2, phtml

I am trying to make changes to the code in a phtml file at `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates`. I have made a new directory and placed the new phtml file to the `app/design/frontend/Swissup/argento-pure2/Magento_Newsletter/templates`. Does this sound correct? I'm unsure of my Theme Vendor and my Theme Name, I guessed them to be Swissup and argento-pure2. When I check using template-hints, it still doesn't use the modified version. What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: tyou are correct ou clean the cache? ou activate the theme?

Comment: Yes, I have done both.

Answer (score 0):

You overrided perfectly.!

If you want to check your applied theme then you can check from admin panel

**Way 1**

Admin panel => Content => Design => Configuration => Edit => Applied Theme

**Way 2**
You can press ctrl+u and check any css or js file. It will show full path with theme name.

Now you will get theme name and override your template(phtml) file in that theme

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But it doesn't work, do I need to include any other files?

Comment: do I need to include any other files? - *No*

Comment: are you overrided in correct theme? if yes then it should work

Comment: yes, I checked the css file in ctul+u. It showed this "pub/static/version1637259097/frontend/Swissup/argento-pure2/en_US/Swissup_Highlight/css/highlight.css" />"

Comment: it's correctt. please make sure you flushed cache after changing in phtml